# Expose "Process builder Platform Event miss" to the outside world

Tags: platform-event

When a process builder registered so to be triggered by a platform event does not find a related matching object, it sends an email that the process builder has failed to find a match but the API succeeds.

This does not make easy to understand from the outside that the match didn't occur: in case of eventually consistent systems this is really annoying since what you would like to do is to re-publish the event later when the matching object has been written on Salesforce

The key point here is that it should be possible via the process builder to publish another event on a "miss" or to expose to the outside world that a miss has occurred, but it seems this is only possible via triggers. Are there declarative solutions to this problem?

Comment: Can you explain what is meant by related matching object?

Comment: Process builder on platform events always need a matching object, they are not like process builder triggered by sobject